# How to mock e.preventDefault in react component's child

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, sinon, enzyme

Hy, I don't know how to mock an inline function in React component's child

My stack: `sinon`, `chai`, `enzyme`;

Component usage:

```
<ListItem onClick={() => someFn()} />
```

Component's render:

```
render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <a href="#" onClick={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.props.onClick();
          }}
        > whatever </a>
      </li>
    );
  }
```

Here we have `onClick` function that calls `e.preventDefault()`. How to tell to `<a href>`(`link`) to not to call `e.preventDefault()`? How can I mock an `onClick`?

Below is what I have tried in tests:

Shallow copy setup

```
function setup() {
  const someFn = sinon.stub();

  const component = shallow(
    <ListItem
      onClick={() => {
        someFn();
      }}
    />
  );

  return {
    component: component,
    actions: someFn,
    link: component.find('a'),
    listItem: component.find('li'),
  }
}
```

And the test

```
  it('simulates click events', () => {
    const { link, actions } = setup();
    link.simulate('click'); //Click on <a href>
    expect(actions).to.have.property('callCount', 1); //will be fine if we remove e.preventDefault()
  });
```

Test's output error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try this

```
link.simulate('click', {
  preventDefault: () => {
  }
 });
```

Comment: I have invoke method, this not works for me

Answer (score 10):

```
 test('simulates click events', () => {
    const preventDefault = jest.fn()
    const e = { preventDefault };
    const component = render(<Component {...props} />);
    const li = component.find('whatever you need').props().onClick(e)

    expect(preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 9):

For those using Jest and `@testing-library` or `react-testing-library`s `fireEvent`, you need to provide an initialised event object, otherwise the event can't be dispatched via your element.

One can then assert on `e.preventDefault` being called by assigning a property to that initialised event:

```js
test('prevents default on click', () => {
  const {getByText} = render(<MyComponent />);
  const button = getByText(/click me/);

  // initialise an event, and assign your own preventDefault
  const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click');
  Object.assign(clickEvent, {preventDefault: jest.fn()});

  fireEvent(button, clickEvent);

  expect(clickEvent.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Similarly for `stopPropagation`.

[Anton Karpenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50366558/895007) for Jest was useful.

Comment: is the last line correct? `event.preventDefault` how does expect know the context of `event`?

Comment: @sidonaldson thanks for picking that up - fixed the example to reference `clickEvent`

Answer (score 6):

Just to note that this is an issue only when using `shallow` enzyme renderer. In case of full DOM renderer `mount`, the event object contains the `preventDefault` method, therefore you don't have to mock it.

Answer (score 4):

You can define *an object with regarding function you will mock* via some testing tool, for example look at **Jest** and **Enzyme**

```
describe('Form component', () => {
  test('deos not reload page after submition', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TodosForm />)
    // an object with some function
    const event = { preventDefault: () => {} }
    // mocks for this function
    jest.spyOn(event, 'preventDefault')
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', event)
    // how would you know that function is called
    expect(event.preventDefault).toBeCalled()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create new object based on jest.fn() with

```
const event = Object.assign(jest.fn(), {preventDefault: () => {}})
```

then use it:

```
element.simulate('click', event);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Web Components and this works for me -

```
  const callback = jest.fn();
  MouseEvent.prototype.stopPropagation = callback;
  const element = createElement({});
  element.shadowRoot.querySelector('ul').click();
  expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```